# How to create row wise CSV for vectorized dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, countvectorizer

What I am trying to do is basically pulling out keywords from a processed file of a log file and creating a vectorized dataframe of those keywords. But when I am writing that dataframe into CSV, words are in the columns and their respective value in the second row.
While **`I want the words to be in rows and their value in second column.`**

*trial.py* :

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS

def removeNumbers(list):
   #doing something

def processFiles(filename):
   #doing something

def readFile(fileName):
   #doing something

# Build our text
processFiles("log.txt")
text = readFile("processedFile.txt")


vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform([text])

counts = pd.DataFrame(matrix.toarray(),
                      columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())



counts.to_csv("keywords_count.csv")
```

*keywords_count.csv* looks like this :

```
,accept,accepted,action,add,address,agent,allocated,api,api_action_sender,api_reader,apihandle,apiinitialize,apiterminate,appl,associate,attempt,available,bd,bdfb,broken,ceased,check_signals,chose,cksm,cl,clcat,client,close,code,complete,conf,configuration,connection,connfd,constructing,control,creating,ctcd,delresp,dereg,deregistering,does,dreg_process,dst,dump,edci,engine,entering,entity,entity_initialize,entries,entry,event,event_establishsessionsend,event_timert_expire,exist,exists,exit,exiting,expect,expired,failed,fc,file,filter,flg,flow,flow_timer_start,flow_timer_stop,forward,gateway,handle,home,hop,if,ifaeddrg_byaddr,ifidx,image,images,index,inf,info,informational,init_policyapi,initialization,initialized,install,interface,ioctl,ip,len,level,lih,link,list,local,locate_configfile,log,loopback,mailbox,mailbox_register,mailslot,mailslot_create,mailslot_send,mailslot_sitter,main,mcast_add,module,msg,necessary,new,node,obj,old,open_socket,operation,os,outgoing,papi_debug,papilogfunc,papiuservalue,path,pathdelta,pathed,pathtear,pipe,policy,process,proterr,proto,qoshandle,qoshd,qosmgr,qosmgr_request,qosmgr_response,query,querying,rapi,raw,rc,read_physical_netif,readbuffer,ready,reason,received,reentering,reg_process,registered,registering,registerwithpolicyapi,registration,remove,req,request,reservation,response,result,resv,resvdelta,resved,resvresp,return,returned,route,router_forward_getoi,rpapi_getpolicydata,rpapi_getspecdata,rpapi_reg_unregflow,rsv,rsvp,rsvp_action_nhop,rsvp_api_open,rsvp_event,rsvp_event_establishsession,rsvp_event_mapsession,rsvp_event_propagate,rsvp_explode_packet,rsvp_flow_statemachine,rsvp_hop,rsvp_parse_objects,rsvpd,rsvpfindactionname,rsvpfindservicedetailsonactname,rsvpgettspec,rsvpputactionname,rsvpremactionname,rthdl,send,sender,sender_withdraw,sending,service,sess,session,sessioned,setsockopt,settcpimage,sigalrm,signal,sigterm,socket,source,specified,src,start,started,state,status,stop,stopped,style,successful,supported,tc,tcp,tcpcs,term,term_policyapi,terminate,terminated,terminator,timer,tout,tr,trace,traffic,traffic_action_oif,traffic_reader,ttl,type,udp,unregistered,unregisterfrompolicyapi,user,using,vlink,warning,wf,writing
0,1,1,1,1,18,1,28,8,1,6,1,3,2,1,1,2,4,2,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,9,2,22,2,1,1,1,2,3,3,2,5,2,20,7,7,1,7,31,1,6,1,6,1,17,1,6,4,8,1,2,4,4,12,7,2,7,7,1,4,1,2,7,1,1,7,7,147,2,14,1,8,1,18,9,5,4,1,4,2,1,1,1,1,1,24,23,20,27,9,7,3,4,1,2,2,2,1,4,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,7,1,2,4,2,2,10,1,3,2,1,2,4,4,6,1,1,4,4,8,12,1,2,12,9,3,1,1,3,2,2,1,4,3,2,6,4,1,20,1,1,1,17,35,11,3,12,4,38,8,1,4,1,7,1,4,26,4,8,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,9,3,3,10,4,4,2,6,8,1,6,12,1,3,4,9,26,2,5,2,4,10,1,2,2,1,1,8,2,2,1,2,6,1,119,2,2,3,4,5,14,1,3,1,1,1,4,4,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose your dataframe:

```
counts.T.to_csv("keywords_count.csv")
```

Comment: After transposing, it does solve the problem. But still the CSV has single column with words and their count just next to them. How to split the words and count into two different columns?

Comment: What do you mean? There are 2 columns in your csv file like "word,count" (comma separated). Do you want to change the separator between word and count columns? Try `counts.T.to_csv("keywords_count.csv", sep='\t')`

Comment: yeah, there are 2 columns but one is empty and both word and it's count is in second column seperated by \t. See [Image](https://i.imgur.com/vJoJyO5.png)
I want word in one column and count in second.

Comment: Try `counts = pd.Series(matrix.toarray()[0], index=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(), name='count').rename_axis('word').reset_index()`. Then `counts.to_csv('keywords_count.csv')`

Comment: Yeah now the CSV is in right format as I wanted. Thanks man!